# Multiple selection in C#

Tags: c#, listbox

I am fetching data from database and i am showing it in multiple select box but i want to show location 1,3,5 items should be selected by default. How?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense...

Comment: We're assuming you mean "a listbox with multiple selection capabilities". Correct?

Comment: after edit, it's (probably) a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831296/programmatically-selecting-items-indexes-in-a-listbox

Comment: Are you using WPF, Windows Forms or ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, you can use [the ListBox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Bind the Listbox to the datasource. A [google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en-GBGB388GB389&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=bind+listbox+to+datasource+c%23) will probably be helpful.

If you mean "how do I select specific items", then [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831296/programmatically-selecting-items-indexes-in-a-listbox) will help.