# How can I programmatically select an item in a listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox, compact-framework, listboxitem, .net-1.1

I have a listbox displaying items from an enum. I want to select/highlight the current value (read from a database) when the listbox displays/the form opens. This code, though:

```
lblSelectedPrinter.Text = AppSettings.ReadSettingsVal("beltprinter");
listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem = listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.IndexOf(lblSelectedPrinter.Text);
```

...does not work. I saw an example using "GetItemAt" here ([Programmatically selecting Items/Indexes in a ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831296/programmatically-selecting-items-indexes-in-a-listbox)) but my stripped down and archaic version of C# (.NET 1.1, C# 2) has no such critter.

### UPDATE

I thought this would work:

```
string currentPrinter = AppSettings.ReadSettingsVal("beltprinter");
lblSelectedPrinter.Text = currentPrinter;
int currentPrinterIndex = listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.IndexOf(currentPrinter);
listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem = currentPrinterIndex;
```

...but it, also, does not (the current printer displays in the label, but the corresponding entry/value in the listbox is not selected).

Comment: what error does it say in the debugger @Clay?

Comment: No debugger; my "debugger" is MessageBox.Show() due to the cobwebby nature of these tools.

Comment: can you put it in a try catch and throw the exception to us?

Comment: Thanks for your help, AmitApollo (I remember when you fought Rocky, by the way). There was no exception, it just wasn't working. It is now; I answered my own question.

Comment: Yeah, the D*mn Russian killed me in the fourth one! +1 for braving .NET 1.1/2.0. Time to leap into the 2010's ;)

Comment: Don't worry - at home I use VS2012 and am most heavily involved now with jQuery*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see you've already solved this, but why not do it the tried and tested way?

```
  lblSelectedPrinter.Text = AppSettings.ReadSettingsVal("beltprinter");
  listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedIndex = -1;
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblSelectedPrinter.Text)) {
    for (int index = 0; index < listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.Count; index++) {
      string item = listBoxBeltPrinters.Items[index].ToString();
      if (lblSelectedPrinter.Text == item) {
        listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem = index;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

This way, you know the `SelectedIndex` value is set to -1 as soon as the text changes, and if it is found in your `ListBox`, that item is selected.

Even better would be to write a handler when the Label control `lblSelectedPrinter` fires the `TextChanged` event.

```
lblSelectedPrinter.TextChanged += new EventHandler(SelectedPrinter_TextChanged);
```

Then, create that Event Handler like shown above:

```
private void SelectedPrinter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedIndex = -1;
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblSelectedPrinter.Text)) {
    for (int index = 0; index < listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.Count; index++) {
      string item = listBoxBeltPrinters.Items[index].ToString();
      if (lblSelectedPrinter.Text == item) {
        listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem = index;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You've already solved your problem, so this is just food for thought.

Comment: if the "tried and tested way" is a nested `if { for { if { break; } } } ` statement, then you know something's wrong

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
listBoxBeltPrinters.SetSelected(listBoxBeltPrinters.FindString("beltprinter"), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = AppSettings.ReadSettingsVal("beltprinter"); //Save it as an int.
listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem = listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.IndexOf(i);
lblSelectedPrinter.Text = listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need it to be an integer. You can use int.Parse to Convert to cast it from string to int.

```
listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem = listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.IndexOf(int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("beltprinter")));
lblSelectedPrinter.Text = listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem.toString();
```

Comment: I have no ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings

After System.Configuration. the only thing available to me is "Assemblies"

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
string currentPrinter = AppSettings.ReadSettingsVal("beltprinter");
lblSelectedPrinter.Text = currentPrinter;
int currentPrinterIndex = listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.IndexOf(currentPrinter);
listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedIndex = currentPrinterIndex;
```

This is the only code required to display, read, and write the settings val:

```
private void PrinterPickerForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Type type = typeof(PrintUtils.BeltPrinterType);
    foreach (FieldInfo field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        string display = field.GetValue(null).ToString();
        listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.Add(display);
    }
    string currentPrinter = AppSettings.ReadSettingsVal("beltprinter");
    lblCurrentPrinter.Text = currentPrinter;
    int currentPrinterIndex = listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.IndexOf(currentPrinter);
    listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedIndex = currentPrinterIndex;
}

private void btnSaveSelectedVal_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string sel = listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem.ToString();
    if (sel != lblCurrentPrinter.Text)
    {
        AppSettings.WriteSettingsVal("beltPrinter", sel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

can you try the following??? It takes from your code, and then uses FindString

```
string currentPrinter = AppSettings.ReadSettingsVal("beltprinter");
lblSelectedPrinter.Text = currentPrinter;
int index = listBoxBeltPrinters.FindString(lblSelectedPrinter.Text);
listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedIndex = index;
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in my response to your previous comment, I already solved it, and added my solution as an answer. And I think I mentioned that I can't use FindString() - it's not available to me in my outdated and outmoded programming environment. Now pardon me while I get back to my abacus...

Answer (score 2):

Combination of `listBoxObject.SetSelected()` and `listBoxObject.FindString()` is an elegant solution. It works for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
lblSelectedPrinter.Text = AppSettings.ReadSettingsVal("beltprinter");

listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem = listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.FindByText(lblSelectedPrinter.Text);
```

**By value:**

```
listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem = listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.FindByValue(1);
```

Comment: Neither "FindByText" nor "FindByValue" is available to me following listBoxBeltPrinters.Items. Using these archaeologist's dreams (VS2003, &c) I feel like I'm fishing in the dark with a plastic pink rod outfitted only with a frayed line that's dangling in a dry creek (I'm going for the Bulwar-Lytton award).

Comment: jaj, the method index=lista.FindString("item") return the index, could be so lista.SetSelected(index,true);

Comment: I don't know what "jaj" means, but FindString() is not available to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use ListBox.ItemContainerStyl in your xaml to set ListBoxItem Style.Style Triggers. There is one example in stackoverflow. It works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).